# How to fix Element is not valid in C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-api-management

I am using this api https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/activitylogs/list#code-try-0 for my azure app to save data to Mongodb.
The response is

```
"value": [
{
  "authorization": {
    "action": "microsoft.support/supporttickets/write",
    "role": "Subscription Admin",
    "scope": "/subscriptions/089bd33f-d4ec-47fe-8ba5-0753aa5c5b33/resourceGroups/MSSupportGroup/providers/microsoft.support/supporttickets/115012112305841"
  },
  "caller": "admin@contoso.com",
  "claims": {
    "aud": "https://management.core.windows.net/",
    "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47/",
    "iat": "1421876371",
    "nbf": "1421876371",
    "exp": "1421880271",
    "ver": "1.0",
    "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid": "1e8d8218-c5e7-4578-9acc-9abbd5d23315",
    "http://schemas.microsoft.com/claims/authnmethodsreferences": "pwd",
    "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier": "2468adf0-8211-44e3-95xq-85137af64708",
    "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn": "admin@contoso.com",
    "puid": "20030000801A118C",
    "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier": "9vckmEGF7zDKk1YzIY8k0t1_EAPaXoeHyPRn6f413zM",
    "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname": "John",
    "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname": "Smith",
    "name": "John Smith",
    "groups": "cacfe77c-e058-4712-83qw-f9b08849fd60,7f71d11d-4c41-4b23-99d2-d32ce7aa621c,31522864-0578-4ea0-9gdc-e66cc564d18c",
    "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name": "admin@contoso.com",
    "appid": "c44b4083-3bq0-49c1-b47d-974e53cbdf3c",
    "appidacr": "2",
    "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/scope": "user_impersonation",
    "http://schemas.microsoft.com/claims/authnclassreference": "1"
  },
  "correlationId": "1e121103-0ba6-4300-ac9d-952bb5d0c80f",
  "description": "",
  "eventDataId": "44ade6b4-3813-45e6-ae27-7420a95fa2f8",
  "eventName": {
    "value": "EndRequest",
    "localizedValue": "End request"
  },
  "httpRequest": {
    "clientRequestId": "27003b25-91d3-418f-8eb1-29e537dcb249",
    "clientIpAddress": "192.168.35.115",
    "method": "PUT"
  },
  "id": "/subscriptions/089bd33f-d4ec-47fe-8ba5-0753aa5c5b33/resourceGroups/MSSupportGroup/providers/microsoft.support/supporttickets/115012112305841/events/44ade6b4-3813-45e6-ae27-7420a95fa2f8/ticks/635574752669792776",
  "level": "Informational",
  "resourceGroupName": "MSSupportGroup",
  "resourceProviderName": {
    "value": "microsoft.support",
    "localizedValue": "microsoft.support"
  },
  "operationId": "1e121103-0ba6-4300-ac9d-952bb5d0c80f",
  "operationName": {
    "value": "microsoft.support/supporttickets/write",
    "localizedValue": "microsoft.support/supporttickets/write"
  },
  "properties": {
    "statusCode": "Created"
  },
  "status": {
    "value": "Succeeded",
    "localizedValue": "Succeeded"
  },
  "subStatus": {
    "value": "Created",
    "localizedValue": "Created (HTTP Status Code: 201)"
  },
  "eventTimestamp": "2015-01-21T22:14:26.9792776Z",
  "submissionTimestamp": "2015-01-21T22:14:39.9936304Z",
  "subscriptionId": "089bd33f-d4ec-47fe-8ba5-0753aa5c5b33"
}
  ],
   "nextLink": "https://management.azure.com/########-####-####-####- 
    ############$skiptoken=######"
 }
```

My class is

```
public class ActivityLogOB
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId IDindex { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public SenderAuthorization authorization { get; set; }
    public string caller { get; set; }
    public LocalizableString category { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> claims { get; set; }
    public string correlationId { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string eventDataId { get; set; }
    public LocalizableString eventName { get; set; }
    public string eventTimestamp { get; set; }
    public HttpRequestInfo httpRequest { get; set; }
    public string level { get; set; }
    public string operationId { get; set; }
    public LocalizableString operationName { get; set; }
    public object properties { get; set; }
    public string resourceId { get; set; }
    public string resourceGroupName { get; set; }
    public string subscriptionId { get; set; }
    public string subscriptionName { get; set; }
    public LocalizableString resourceProviderName { get; set; }
    public LocalizableString resourceType { get; set; }
    public LocalizableString status { get; set; }
    public LocalizableString subStatus { get; set; }
    public string submissionTimestamp { get; set; }
    public string tenantId { get; set; }
}
```

I get a error when try to covert

```
Dictionary<string, string> claims { get; set; }
```

This error: Element "http://schemas.microsoft.com/claims/authnclassreference" is not valid.
How can I fix this.

Here is my code:

```
public static void ActivityLog_Insert(ActivityLogOB obj, string subscriptionId, string subscriptionName, string time){
   var client = new MongoClient(ServerMongodb);
   var server = client.GetServer();
   var database = server.GetDatabase("ActivityLog");
   var collection = database.GetCollection<ActivityLogOB>("ActivityLog " + time);
   ActivityLogOB vn = new ActivityLogOB();
   vn.authorization = obj.authorization;
   vn.caller = obj.caller;
   vn.category = obj.category;
   vn.claims = obj.claims;
   vn.correlationId = obj.correlationId;
   vn.description = obj.description;
   vn.eventDataId = obj.eventDataId;
   vn.eventName = obj.eventName;
   vn.eventTimestamp = obj.eventTimestamp;
   vn.httpRequest = obj.httpRequest;
   vn.id = obj.id;
   vn.level = obj.level;
   vn.operationId = obj.operationId;
   vn.operationName = obj.operationName;
   vn.properties = obj.properties;
   vn.resourceId = obj.resourceId;
   vn.resourceProviderName = obj.resourceProviderName;
   vn.resourceType = obj.resourceType;
   vn.status = obj.status;
   vn.subStatus = obj.subStatus;
   vn.submissionTimestamp = obj.submissionTimestamp;
   vn.subscriptionId = obj.subscriptionId;
   vn.subscriptionName = subscriptionName;
   vn.resourceGroupName = obj.resourceGroupName;
   vn.tenantId = obj.tenantId;
   collection.Insert(vn);
   server.Disconnect();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create another class as "LocalizableString" for "claims".